# Revenue by year by month giving error (invalid syntax ',')

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT 
    year(T1.Docdate) as [year],                     
    Month (T1..Docdate) as [Month]                      
FROM 
    (
         Year, (T1.Doctotal) AS [BAL], year(T1.Docdate) as [year]  
     FROM 
         dbo.OCRD T0                        
     LEFT JOIN 
         dbo.OINV T1 ON T1.CardCode = T0.CardCode  
     WHERE
         T0.[CardType] ='C'                         
     UNION                      
     SELECT 
         Year, -(T1.Doctotal) AS [BAL], year(T1.Docdate) as [year]  
     FROM 
         dbo.OCRD T0                        
     LEFT JOIN 
         dbo.ORIN T1 ON T1.CardCode = T0.CardCode  
     WHERE 
         T0.[CardType] = 'C') S                     
PIVOT 
    (SUM(S.[BAL]) FOR [year] IN ([Jan], [Feb], [March], [April])) P
```

Comment: You have two `FROM` on the main part of the query, `..` in the field list, etc...

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use a subquery for your first `FROM` statement? You're forgetting a `SELECT`. And the decimal problem Marc B pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing `SELECT` in your sub query

```
SELECT year(T1.Docdate) as [year],                      
Month (T1..Docdate) as [Month]                      

FROM **(SELECT** Year, (T1.Doctotal) AS [BAL],year(T1.Docdate) as [year]  FROM dbo.OCRD T0                     
        LEFT JOIN dbo.OINV T1 ON T1.CardCode = T0.CardCode  Where  T0.[CardType] ='C'                         
        UNION                     
        SELECT Year, -(T1.Doctotal)  AS [BAL],year(T1.Docdate) as [year]  FROM dbo.OCRD T0                        
        LEFT JOIN dbo.ORIN T1 ON T1.CardCode = T0.CardCode  Where  T0.[CardType] ='C'                       
) S                     
          PIVOT  (SUM(S.[BAL]) FOR [year] IN                        
         ([Jan],[Feb],[March],[April])) P
```

Answer (score 0):

Your nested query is incomplete as you don't have the `SELECT` keyword. The correct query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    year(T1.Docdate) as [year],                     
    Month (T1..Docdate) as [Month]                      
FROM 
    (
     SELECT Year, (T1.Doctotal) AS [BAL], year(T1.Docdate) as [year]  
     FROM 
         dbo.OCRD T0                        
     LEFT JOIN 
         dbo.OINV T1 ON T1.CardCode = T0.CardCode  
     WHERE
         T0.[CardType] ='C'                         
     UNION                      
     SELECT 
         Year, -(T1.Doctotal) AS [BAL], year(T1.Docdate) as [year]  
     FROM 
         dbo.OCRD T0                        
     LEFT JOIN 
         dbo.ORIN T1 ON T1.CardCode = T0.CardCode  
     WHERE 
         T0.[CardType] = 'C') S                     
PIVOT 
    (SUM(S.[BAL]) FOR [year] IN ([Jan], [Feb], [March], [April])) P
```